# Continue after finish to read all rows in Maatwebsite Excel package for laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5 and Maatwebsite Excel package for read and write Excel files, but I don't know exactly how manage the next situation

```
public function readExcel(Request $request){
    $content = [];

    Excel::load('file.xls', function($reader){

        $content = $reader->get();
    });

    // do more somethings and return
    return $content;
}
```

The thing is, when I return $content, ther is nothing in the variable, I have a idea that $content have the initial value and Excel::load still not finish and the new value of $content has not setted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try by declaring a variable in class.
For Ex:

```
class TestController extends Controller {
   public $content = [];

   public function readExcel(Request $request){

    Excel::load('file.xls', function($reader){

        $this->content = $reader->get();
    });

    // do more somethings and return
    return $this->content;
}

}
```

Another Way :

```
public function readExcel(Request $request){

    $excel = Excel::load('file.xls', function($reader){

        $content = $reader->get();
    });

    dd($excel->get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just a question, why my code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the contents of your closure. Try this instead:

```
public function readExcel(Request $request)
{
    $content = Excel::load('file.xls', function($reader) {
        return $reader->get();
    });

    // do more somethings and return
    return $content;
}
```